# Collect all fields having given Modifier(s)

Tags: java, reflection, field, access-modifiers

I want to collect all fields which have given Modifier(s) of a class. I have written following pieces of codes:

```
/**
 * Method getFields
 * @author TapasB
 * @since 03-Nov-2013 - 2:03:17 pm
 * @version DAM 1.0
 * @param instanceClass
 * @return
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static List<Field> getFields(Class<?> instanceClass) {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();        
    Class<?> searchType = instanceClass;

    while (!Object.class.equals(searchType) && searchType != null) {
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(searchType.getDeclaredFields()));
        searchType = searchType.getSuperclass();
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList(selectDistinct(fields, "name")));
}

/**
 * Method getFields
 * @author TapasB
 * @since 03-Nov-2013 - 2:31:59 pm
 * @version DAM 1.0
 * @param instanceClass
 * @param includedModifiers
 * @param excludedModifiers
 * @return
 */
public static List<Field> getFields(Class<?> instanceClass, int[] includedModifiers, int[] excludedModifiers) {
    List<Field> fields = getFields(instanceClass);
    List<Field> filteredFields = new ArrayList<Field>();

    if(ArrayUtils.isEmpty(includedModifiers)) {
        filteredFields.addAll(fields);
    } else {
        for(Field field : fields) {
            boolean fieldCanBeAdded = false;

            for(int includedModifier : includedModifiers) {
                if((includedModifier & field.getModifiers()) != 0) {
                    fieldCanBeAdded = true;
                }
            }

            if(fieldCanBeAdded) {
                filteredFields.add(field);
            }
        }
    }               

    if(ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(excludedModifiers)) {
        Iterator<Field> fieldIterator = filteredFields.iterator();

        while (fieldIterator.hasNext()) {
            Field field = fieldIterator.next();
            boolean fieldNeedsToBeRemoved = false;

            for(int excludedModifier : excludedModifiers) {
                if((excludedModifier & field.getModifiers()) != 0) {
                    fieldNeedsToBeRemoved = true;
                }
            }

            if(fieldNeedsToBeRemoved) {
                fieldIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }   

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(filteredFields);
}
```

The method `getFields(Class<?> instanceClass)` searchs for fields in an iterative manner to all the super classes of the given class and stops at `Object`.

Here the [`selectDistinct`][2] is the method of [LambdaJ API][3]. It removes the fields with same name which is present in the parent class also in child class.

I was wondering if it is a good way to achieve what I want.

To run it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    int[] includedModifiers = new int[]{Modifier.PRIVATE};
    int[] excludedModifiers = new int[]{Modifier.FINAL};
    List<Field> fields = getFields(ArrayList.class, includedModifiers, excludedModifiers);

    for(Field field : fields) {
        System.out.println(field.getName());
    }
}
```

The `main` will print only the fields which have modifier only `private` and exclude the `private final`.

There is no issue so far I found with this code. I just want to know if there is any better solution exists or not.

Comment: It would help if you told us what result you want, and what result you get. What's the problem?

Comment: @JBNizet hello. There is no issue so far I found with this code. I just want to know if there is any better solution exists or not.

Comment: If you need to improve a working code, you may post to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel hello. thanks for pointing. How can I move this thread to there?

Comment: We can't move it to codereview. You need a moderator for that. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stackexchange-site).